# export as .xls file not work when large data

Tags: javascript, xls

I am using the javascript code for export html table to .xls file.Its work in crome and when data is not large.But when data is large then it shows me error like

[image]

The code which i have used for export the table as .xls file is as below:

```
function exportDiv() {
    //working on crome perfectly       
        var dt = new Date();
        var day = dt.getDate();
        var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = dt.getFullYear();
        var hour = dt.getHours();
        var mins = dt.getMinutes();
        var postfix = day + "." + month + "." + year + "_" + hour + "." + mins;
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
        var table_div = document.getElementById('tbl-1');
        var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
        a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
        a.download = 'exported_table_' + postfix + '.xls';
        a.click();
        e.preventDefault();

}
```

I have also sufficient 4 gb ram so i think its not memory limit problem.

Can you please help me for how to export large data?
**Edit:** I ahve used this way also

```
 var table_html=encodeURIComponent(table_div.outerHTML);
```

But still same error come.

Comment: Not answering your question, but you can make use of [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) instead of replacing special characters yourself.

Comment: getting into infinite loop i suppose

Comment: @Arun Killu: only once this function is called and in that i have just download the table as .xls file so where is the infinite loop?

Comment: @user1181940 for me your code is working fine

Comment: @Arun Killu: This code is also working for me but the problem is that when too much data in table like 500 rows in table then it will show the error page as shown above

Comment: BTW, any reason you're using `replace` instead of `encodeURIComponent`?

Comment: @NOrdvind: Nope there is no any reason for use replace

Comment: Could you specify, how big is the table? How many rows, how many cells in a row, how many characters in a cell? Approximately at least.

Comment: @Nordvind: i have 3500 rows and 30 columns in my table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have called the tableToexcel function on button click like as below and it is working fine in firefix.

```
<a id="dlink"  style="display:none;"></a>

    var tableToExcel = (function () {
            var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
            , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
            return function (table, name, filename) {
                if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
                var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }

                document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
                document.getElementById("dlink").download = filename;
                document.getElementById("dlink").click();

            }
        })();
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you've hit the 2 MB URL limit in Chrome. You can read about it here - [issue link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=69227). I suggest you try your app in Firefox, if it works, then that is the issue.

Comment: But my code is not work in firefox.When i click on export button then it will not doing anything.I have also check the error log but there is no any error.

Answer (score 1):

excel sheet has got a character limit for 32767 characters similar to that of an excel cell.

for reference check this link : http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx

Comment: This is **NOT** an excel file, it's just a *.htm file, which can be opened by Excel. It will warn you about extension and file format mismatch.

Comment: worksheet have 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns.I have table with 3500 rows and 30 columns.So i think it will not ristrict me to exlode.