# Export large html table to excel

Tags: javascript, excel

I want to export html table to excel so I'm using this javascript code:

```
var tableToExcel = (function () {
        var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
                , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table x:str>{table}</table></body></html>'
                , base64 = function (s) {
                    return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
                }
        , format = function (s, c) {
            return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                return c[p];
            })
        }
        return function (table, name) {
            if (!table.nodeType)
                table = document.getElementById(table);
            var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
            window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
        }
    })();
```

At first,this code work fine form me ,but in very large table it does not because the uri is too long for the window.location.href.
Is their any soution to export large table to Excel ?

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401638/export-as-xls-file-not-work-when-large-data

Comment: and can refer to this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317951/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript-jquery-is-not-working-properl

Answer (score 3):

I found one way to solve this issue using  [FileSaver.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImQ2R.png)
  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImQ2R.png): https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/ Please check followings

HTML
[image]

Javascript

[image]

this is working fine for me with large data set of HTML table.

Answer (score 3):

You can download large HTML Table used this function.

```
function ExportToExcel(tableid) {
        var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
        var textRange; var j = 0;
        tab = document.getElementById(tableid);//.getElementsByTagName('table'); // id of table
        if (tab==null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (tab.rows.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        for (j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) {
            tab_text = tab_text + tab.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";
            //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
        }

        tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
        tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");//remove if u want links in your table
        tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, ""); // remove if u want images in your table
        tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

        if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
        {
            txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
            txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
            txtArea1.document.close();
            txtArea1.focus();
            sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "download.xls");
        }
        else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
            //sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
            try {
                var blob = new Blob([tab_text], { type: "application/vnd.ms-excel" });
                window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                link = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                a = document.createElement("a");
                if (document.getElementById("caption")!=null) {
                    a.download=document.getElementById("caption").innerText;
                }
                else
                {
                    a.download = 'download';
                }

                a.href = link;

                document.body.appendChild(a);

                a.click();

                document.body.removeChild(a);
            } catch (e) {
            }


        return false;
        //return (sa);
    }
```

Comment: Dude!! this is the best, it generates 10000 rows, 25 columns instantly

Comment: I am getting error- "file format and extension don't match excel could be corrupted or unsafe" after opening file